# Infinite for loop with promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I want to fetch some data from firebase database and i have an array with a couple of uids. Those uids must replace the ${} in the string so that i can obtain the reference. I iterate through the items with a for loop and use await to wait for the response and then set a state in react native. Even though i use async and await, i run into an infinite loop. Can someone explain me why is this happening?

```
async function getUserCars(){
 // listedCars is an array of uids
  for(const listedCar of listedCars){
    const tmp = await database().ref(`/listedCars/${listedCar}`).once('value', snapshot => {
      console.log("userCars in async func: ", userCars)
      setUserCars(userCars.concat(snapshot.val()))
      
    })

}
}
```

listedCars is a state, an array initialized on mount.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  
  const user = auth().currentUser
  if(user){
  database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/listedCars`)
  .on('value',snapshot=>{
    if(snapshot.val()){
      console.log('cars listed:')
      console.log(snapshot.val())
      setListedCars(snapshot.val())
      console.log(listedCars)
      
  

    }else{
      console.log('no cars listed')
      setListedCars(null);
    }
    
  })
}
}


},[])
```

In firebase, listedCars is stored like this:

```
users
|
|
|
----uid
     |
     |
     |
      --- listedCars
                |
                |
                |
                 --- 0: car_uid0
                 --- 1: car_uid1
```

userCars is also a state.

```
  const [listedCars, setListedCars] = useState(null)
  const [userCars, setUserCars] = useState([])
```

Comment: How exactly is `listedCars` defined, and what does other code do with it? There's no other way for this to be an infinite loop other than `listedCars` constantly getting new items appended.

Comment: Also what is `setUserCars`, a react state hook? Does it cause rerendering and `getUserCars()` to be called again?

Comment: Looks like the setUserCars was causing the rerender and re-execute the getUserCars() function. Thank you.